# Fan noise on laptops with AMD graphics cards

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, fan, intel-graphics, amd-graphics-card

**Windows 10** operating system is installed on my laptop (**Sony VAIO**). And when I bought the laptop, **Windows 7** was installed on it.
Here's my problem.
There are two graphics cards on the laptop. One is ***Intel HD Graphics 3000*** and the other is ***"AMD Radeon 6600M and 6700M"*** series graphics cards.

***Whenever I open and shutdown my laptop or open any program (such as Google, PyCharm, VMware, etc.) my laptop fan starts *making a lot of noise* (badly, similar to the noise in server cases).***
But there is no cleaning problem. How many times have I cleaned the flower-like fan on the motherboard, lubricated the motor of the fan, made a thermal paste, briefly cleaned all kinds of things. I also installed Windows 10 from scratch.
It also has ***8 GB RAM, 256 GB Samsung SSD 860 EVO*** installed.

My processor is **i5-2410M**. Licensed Windows 10 Pro. All drivers are installed.
I think the problem is with the graphics card (I'm just thinking, but can't find a solution).
I don't work with graphics (Photoshop, CorelDraw (I don't play any games)). If I turn off any of the graphics cards, will my problem be solved? If I turn it off, which one is recommended to turn off?

***If this is not the solution, how can I solve my problem?***
Because the noise is now mentally penetrating my brain and getting on my nerves.

Comment: Did the issue persist when you were on Windows 7?

Comment: No, there was no problem. It's been a month or two since I switched to Windows 10. There wasn't that much noise in the beginning.

Comment: If the fan is loud while starting programs it is the one from CPU. Your GPUs have nothing to with the noise. Most manufacturer provide programs to switch CPU in fast and loud or silent mode. Most likely on Windows 7 there was such a program installed and thus the CPU fan was not so busy.

Comment: When it was Windows 7, I did a clean install a few times, but there was no such problem. So there was no other setup.

Comment: Is there anything related to fan performance/power options in the laptop bios, just in case? Generally, laptop bios'es may not be as feature rich as desktop boards. Still just to check.

Comment: Nothing fan related in BIOS controls. There are things like virtualization technology, system information, but nothing about cpu and fan.

Comment: Neither of your GPUs are qualified for Win10. Both were abandoned [or as the makers prefer to call it, "legacied"] in2015.

Comment: So what can I do if this is the case? Because Windows 7 does not support many programs.

Comment: Unless you can write a driver that builds the necessary support for the hardware into the current software there is nothing you can do. You may not like that answer, but that is the answer that exists and that you must reckon with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you can write a driver that builds the necessary support for the hardware into the current software there is nothing you can do. You may not like that answer, but that is the answer that exists and that you must reckon with.

Hardware doesn't just work with software by magic.

You may be able to, with research and persistence, find some unique hit of code under a digital rock that fixes your problem, but, to the best of the knowledge of the several people who have helped you here, it is clear the root problem is that the hardware you have is not supported fully by the software you wish to run.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand that there is no other solution. While updating Windows 10, it was installing all the graphic drivers by itself. But I did something like this. I set all of AMD's configurations to best battery life and boom.. noise was reduced by 70 percent.

Comment: I've upgraded laptops past their supported OS level and dealt with default driver setups before. We're far better off today than we were 15-20 years ago, but there's a few annoyances you just have to deal with.